# google map v3 service - find minimum distance while driving

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test").gmap3({
      getroute:{
        options:{
            origin:"<?php echo $pickup; ?>",
            destination:"<?php echo  $destination; ?>",
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        },
        callback: function(results){
          if (!results) return;
          $(this).gmap3({
            map:{
              options:{
                zoom: 13
              }
            },
            directionsrenderer:{
              //container: $(document.createElement("div")).addClass("googlemap").insertAfter($("#test")),
              options:{ directions:results }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });


});//]]>  

</script>
```

So this the code, using gmap3 (gmap3.net)
So, problem is, it is showing the quickest way in minute.
If i want to go from A to B, may be it have 3 different route where 50 minutes 30 miles, 55 minutes 17 miles, 57 minutes 19 miles and it will first select 50 minutes/30miles route. But i need the route with minimum miles (55min/17miles).
is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

`results` will contain an array with the 3 `routes` .

Find the desired route within this array(should be the 2nd in this case) and pass the index of the route via the `routeIndex`-property `options`(default is 0):

```
options:{ directions:results, routeIndex: 1 }
```